# Text comparison of phrases in two data-frames and getting the output at matching phrases with sequence and index

Tags: python, dataframe, nlp, spacy

Two datasets df and df1 are in columns in row-wise split, but separated by fullstop '.' as complete sentence.
I want to match the dataset phrases which are present in both and and get the dataset at the matching sentences with the index of superset df.

I can only make if the text is plain, but not in the column-wise. If the spaCy or nlp with language model can help to handle this issue?

```
df:

index ID-0 ID-1 text
0 4 20 This
1 6 8 is 
2 8 6 an 
3 12 15 apple
4 29 9.
5 45 5 The
6 56 8 apple
7 60 10 is 
8 62 15 sweet
9 65 2 .
10 66 1 This 
11 68 2 is
12 70 6 very
13 73 4 good
14 75 1 fruit
15 76 3 .
16 78 1 I 
17 82 0 like
18 90 6 to 
19 95 8 eat
20 99 2 apple
21 100 0 .

df1

idx text
1 The
2 apple
3 is 
4 sweet
5 .
6 I 
7 like
8 to 
9 eat
10 apple
11 .

output:

index ID-0 ID-1 text    
5 45 5 The
6 56 8 apple
7 60 10 is 
8 62 15 sweet
9 65 2 .
16 78 1 I 
17 82 0 like
18 90 6 to 
19 95 8 eat
20 99 2 apple
21 100 0 .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be pretty simple:

```
df_new = df[df.text.isin(df1.text)]
```

Comment: with the repeated words, this solution is not correct, and also, with the sequence it is disturb. it should take one sentence as one element. Only than, the solution of something like this should work.